# Why not get the offset to the read-write functions of my driver?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm programming a driver that performs reads and writes to memory locations that have been mapped (in driver open) with:

```
request_mem_region(0x62200000,0x0006C,secuencial);

contador = ioremap_nocache(0x62200000,0x0006C   );
```

where: 0x62200000,0x0006C is the memory location and size of a ipcore that has been instantiated in memory.
"secuencial" is the name of the device driver.

contador is a void* (it's a pointer to the virtual address)

according to my reading and writing functions in the code of my device driver:

```
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *filp, char *buffer,size_t length, loff_t * offset)  

static ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, char *buffer,size_t length, loff_t * offset)
```

and my file operations:

```
static struct file_operations fops = {
    .read    = device_read,
    .write   = device_write,
    .open    = device_open,
    .release = device_release
};
```

from my program in c, I use a function from my library with:

```
read (fd_secuencial,buffer_lectura,199, offset_read);

write( fd_secuencial,  msg,  10, offset_write);
```

where the variables are:

```
loff_t offset_read=0x00000004;
loff_t offset_write=0x00000044;
```

and fd_secuencial is a file descriptor to the device driver obtained in the open:

```
fd_secuencial = open("/dev/secuencial", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

buffer and msg are buffers to read/write the data.

The problem is that the offset  never comes to my reading/writing functions in the driver,

I print with:
printk(KERN_ALERT "Offset: %llu\n", *offset);

and offset is always 0....

what's wrong with my code? any ideas?

I changed the position to access the file from the reading function by

```
filp-> f_pos = integer_different_values​​.
```

And no readings are taken to different memory locations mapped.
That is, the "f_pos" changes, but not access the file as if it were a block of memory (which is the approach that came holding).

If I increase the memory location to which I access with "contador" achievement take readings correctly.

I'm suspecting that the function device_read / write is defined but loff_t * pos field is not implemented in the method of the function.
If I call the function read from the application, with 5 parameters, the compiler gives no warning and the execution is normal (but obviously taking into account the first 3 parameters)

Thus, I can not pass from the application to the function device_read / write driver, offset as the 4th parameter.

The correct way to call the method is as follows:

```
loff_t offset = 16;
loff_t * off = &offset;
```

In this way, you pass the offset value to a pointer called off (which is requesting the function prototype)

thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Is this a character device? They don't allow seeking as far as I understand so an offset parameter would be kind of redundant.

Comment: yes, its a character device driver, i want to use de offset in the ioread and iowrite functions:

ioread32(contador + *offset); 
iowrite32(contador + *offset);

Comment: This is starting to sounding like a XY problem. Setting aside the issue that character devices are not seekable, why are you using that offset in your IO read/write functions?

Comment: because in the memory are ipcore registers, that are read-write, each register have 32bits of size
for example, the first register writing accepts certain types of data, and the results are obtained in the register whose offset is= 0x044

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my question was clear. I meant, why are you letting userspace programs write directly to the register space? Shouldn't your kernel driver be abstracting the device specifics and provide some sort of API instead of letting a userspace program write directly to the registers?

Comment: for now that's not the problem. The system is embedded in a zedboard, which has a basic linux and ipcore instantiated (in the memory possition 0x62200000) . With cross-compiled programs, tested ipcore operation.

Comment: If you just want to write to the register from userspace, you don't need to write a whole kernel driver. Just open `/dev/mem` and seek to offset `0x62200000` plus whatever offset you need..

Answer (score 1):

You may implement a separate seek function with character devices as described in LDD3 here: http://tjworld.net/books/ldd3/#SeekingADevice.

You may use the llseek field of the file_operations struct to assign a seek function with the prototype:

```
loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t, int);
```

The user application or API will then use the user-space function [lseek()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) function to exercise it.

However if you are performing operations on registers that have side effects other than reading data from or writing data to your device, you should probably use the ioctl() interface and provide an API wrapper.  See http://tjworld.net/books/ldd3/#TheIoctlMethod.

Comment: loff_t its a long long (according to linux device drivers) like:

loff_t variable= 0x0000004;

this is right?

Comment: I just realized that I had copied `read()` instead of `llseek()` from the file_operations struct.  I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually, the size of loff_t is implementation dependent, but for most systems it is probably safe to assume it's a `long long`. In the kernel (http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.33/include/linux/types.h#L50) loff_t is defined as __kernel_loff_t, which is defined as a long long for both x86 archs, but a long for arm.  This seems to be independent of the definition of off_t in the user space library. As to your question though, the statement you provide is syntactically correct.

Comment: i have this warning in llseek from mi application:
(.text+0xa8): warning: the `llseek' function may be dangerous; use `lseek64' instead.

I modified the fop but not access the lseek method in the driver

the call is:
llseek(fd_secuencial, 0x0000000000000012, 0);

the fop is:

static struct file_operations fops = {
 .read    = device_read,
 .llseek  = device_llseek,
 .write   = device_write,
 .open    = device_open,
 .release = device_release
};

and the llseek method is:
static loff_t device_llseek(struct file *, loff_t, int);

thank you very much

Comment: The man page for `lseek64()` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lseek64.3.html) says "All the above functions are implemented in terms of [the _llseek system call]".  I'm guessing that the `_llseek` system call is what calls your modules `llseek()` file operation.  You shouldn't have to change any fop to implement `lseek64()`.